# detecting when the camera view is blocked (black frame)

Tags: python, opencv, camera, contour, background-subtraction

I'm trying to detect camera tampering (lens being blocked, resulting in a black frame). The approach I have taken so far is to apply background subtraction and then finding contours post thresholding the foreground mask. Next, I find the area of each contour and if the contour area is higher than a threshold value (say, larger than 3/4th of the camera frame area), then the camera is said to be tampered.
Although upon trying this approach, there is a false tamper alert, even when the camera captures full view.
Not sure, how to go about this detection.
Any help shall be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to compute the median of the image. Than you can use a simple threshold on the median to detect a blocked camera. Of course the median is not flexible in detecting 3/4 of the camera being blocked. But you also also loop over the pixels yourself and count the ones that are below a certain threshold and then compute the percentage of the field being blocked.

Here is a link where yo can see how to compute the median [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/176494/how-to-calculate-the-median-of-pixel-values-in-opencv-python/)

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause for this error could be mild jitters in the frame that occur due to mild shaking of the camera

If your background subtraction algorithm isn't tolerant enough to low-value colour changes, then a tamper alert will be triggered even if you shake the camera a bit.

I would suggest using MOG2 for background subtraction

Answer (score 0):

Take a snapshot from your camera and save it.
And run this python code. If you haven't PIL lib you have to install it.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('yourCamSnapshot.jpg')
pixels = im.getdata()

blackThresh=30    #30 is RGB value
nblack=0

for pixel in pixels:
    if(pixel[0]<=blackThresh and pixel[1]<=blackThresh and pixel[2]<=blackThresh):
        nblack=nblack+1

n=len(pixels)

if (nblack / float(n)) > 0.8:    #0.8 is 80% black
    print("raise exception")
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Amritanjan/detecting-when-the-camera-view-is-blocked  can be used for basic one, it can be improve if we have more detail of the einviroment

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34601803)